# Execute order only once in 4 hour window even though executing orders on the 15M timeframe

Tags: pine-script-v5

I would like to execute a buy/sell on the 15m timeframe but only once within a 4 hour timeframe (the current 4hr bar).
So if there is other orders found to execute on the 15m timeframe after one has executed, they do not fire.
Once the next 4 hour bar starts, it can execute one order.
Hope somebody can assist - thanks.

Getting too many orders firing within that window.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mod (%) operator to authorize a new order each new 4h bar :

```
var authorize_new_order = true

if hour % 4 == 0 and minute(time) == 0
    authorize_new_order := true

if my_condition_to_enter_trade and authorize_new_order
    authorize_new_order := false
    // code to take the trade here
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I tried it but did not seem to work. I think it is because for one whole hour it can set authorize_new_order to true eg. between 4am-5am but I am just wanting to say if it executes an order at 4.20am and wants to execute other ones at 4.25am and 4.30am then those 2 will not execute.

Comment: @BradP I edit my answer with your precision.

Comment: @BradP don't forget to accept to answer if it help you